# Can I compile mysql, php in IPhone or IPod ( or get already built ones )?

Tags: iphone, mysql, ios, build, compilation

I have an unused IPod touch 2.5g ( firmware version 4.2 ).
And I want to make it a web server that can serve Wordpress blog.
So I need **Http server, PHP and MySQL server**.

**Lighttpd**
I installed lighttpd as an HTTP server ( instead of Apache ... It was the easiest thing that I could find.

**Others...**
Now, I am stuck with finding others.
No package available in Cydia ... ( My IPod touch is jailbroken. )
No guide to get them.

So I am considering compile them by myself.
But I don't have any clue which I can do it or How to do it...

Could you let me know how to do it.. what I need .. anything about it ?
Or if there is a already built package, It must be the coolest thing. :)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at http://ios-webstack.tk .

iOS WebStack has all you need!

Already built cydia packages like:

- Newest Lighttpd version
- Newest PHP version (with GD, MySQL and more )
- New MySQL version
- ownCloud
- Wordpress
- Contao
- TYPO3
- WebsiteBaker
- GetSimple
- DokuWiki
- phpMyAdmin
- FreeType 2
- ImageMagick
- GraphicsMagick
- and more

You will also get all needed information to compile your own iDevice webserver at http://code.google.com/p/cydia-ios-lighttpd-php-mysql-web-stack/wiki/Main

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install `ssh` and an `ftpd` on it, as well, just so you get cracking on it from your computer's command line.  I don't believe iOS has any kind of compiler built-in, so you'll want to try to grab `gcc` or `g++` from Cydia.  Otherwise, you'll have to download the Xcode SDK and use the library files from there to compile php for your phone from your computer... good luck!

If you're familiar with programming you can compile c/c++ code inside of an Objective-C program so you *could* write an app which encapsulates php that the phone would run.  Wish I could help you more with this.  How much programming experience have you got?